# Using bash variable in perl parameter

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

Ubuntu, terminal window, bash shell:

```
alex@d120432:~$ echo $0
bash
alex@d120432:~$ echo $(perl -e 'print "a"x2')
aa
alex@d120432:~$ i=2
echo $i
2
alex@d120432:~$ echo $(perl -e 'print "a"x$i')

alex@d120432:~$
```

Is there syntax which allows to substitute `$i` with 2, so that the second  `echo` command prints `xx` like the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get quoting right:

```
i=2
perl -le "print 'a' x $i"
```

```
aa
```

Comment: Thank you. I found that my case is more complicated, can you see this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60074869/perl-and-bash-variable-substitution-with-hexadecimal-characters-and-repeat-coun