# perl and bash variable substitution, with hexadecimal characters and repeat count

Tags: linux, bash, perl, command-line

```
alex@d120432:~$ echo $0
bash
alex@d120432:~$ perl -e 'print "\x41\x42\x43\x44\x0a"x2'
ABCD
ABCD
alex@d120432:~$ i=2
alex@d120432:~$ echo $i
2
alex@d120432:~$ perl -e 'print "\x41\x42\x43\x44\x0a" x $i'
alex@d120432:~$
```

Is it possible to get the same output in the second `perl` command? I cannot find correct syntax to use `i` as repeat count.

Comment: `perl -e "print \"\x41\x42\x43\x44\x0a\" x $i"` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to escape inner double quotes and use double quotes in shell for variable expansion:

```
perl -e "print \"\x41\x42\x43\x44\x0a\" x $i"
```

```
ABCD
ABCD
```

Following variant may also work:

```
perl -e 'print "\x41\x42\x43\x44\x0a" x '$i
```

Answer (score 1):

While Perl uses the double-quote for interpolation, just like the shell, Perl provides the `qq{}` [alternative](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators).

The `{}` delimiters may be any pair you wish. Using this construct can eliminate the need to escape quote characters in the situation described; for example:

```
perl -e "print qq(\x41\x42\x43\x44\x0a) x $i"
```